# A question about the sum of strictly increasing functions preserving the "sum of the arguments".

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\{f_{i}\}_{i=1}^{I}$ are strictly increasing, real valued functions. If 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{I}f_{i}(x_{i})>\sum_{i=1}^{I}f_{i}(y_{i})$$
then is it true that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{I}(x_{i})>\sum_{i=1}^{I}(y_{i})$$

Comment: Do you mean to say that $f_{i}$ is an increasing function for each $i$, or that the sequence $\{f_{i}\}$ is increasing i.e. $f_{1}(x)<f_{2}(x)<...$ for each $x$?

Comment: Each $f_{i}$ is a strictly increasing function, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally false since for example, if $f_1(x) = x$ and $f_2(x) = \ln(x)$ $$101 = 1 + \ln(e^{100}) > 0 + \ln(e^{100} + 2)\simeq 100$$ but $$1 + e^{100} < e^{100} + 2$$

Comment: I think your second inequality is backwards.

Comment: Yes you are right ! I fixed the example ;)

Comment: Great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take $f_{1}(x) = x^{2}$ for $x \ge 0$ and $f_{2}(x) = x^{4}$ for $x \ge 0$. Choose $x_{1} = 1$, $x_{2}=4$, $y_{1}=2$ and $y_{2}=3$. We have $$f_{1}(x_{1}) = 1 \quad f_{2}(x_{2}) = 256$$ and $$f_{1}(y_{1}) = 4 \quad f_{2}(y_{2}) = 81.$$
Thus $f_{1}(x_{1})+f_{2}(x_{2}) = 1+256 = 257 > f_{1}(y_{1})+f_{2}(y_{2}) = 85$ but $x_{1}+x_{2}=y_{1}+y_{2}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there a case where $\sum y_{i}>\sum x_{i}$? Or, in my original question, can you replace the strong inequality (the last one) with a weak one?

Comment: I believe so. Take the same pair of functions I defined and choose $x_{1} = 1$, $x_{2}=8$, $y_{1}=7$ and $y_{2}=3$, for example.